# Need to copy one image to another image ROI

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to copy one image layer to another image ROI. My code is given below.

```
Mat4b src= imread("path");
Mat3b dest = imread("path");
Rect roi = Rect(179,539,src.cols,src.rows); //src.cols = 1186 and src.rows= 1134 after scaling.
Mat destinationROI = dest(roi);
src.copyTo(destinationROI);
imwrite("destinationROI.png", destinationROI);
```

The input src is [image]
The input dest is [image]

But the output got is the same dest image. 
Then I tried to save destinationROI befre copying. The output I got is [image] Which is correct one. Copying the src is also working. But it does not make any effect in the dest image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is to confirm that @ypnos *educated guess* was right (nice call, btw).

---

Take a look at this code, that performs the same operations as yours:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    Mat4b m4b(50, 50, Vec4b(0, 255, 0, 255));   // blue image, 4 channels
    Mat3b m3b(100, 100, Vec3b(255, 0, 0));      // green image, 3 channels

    cout << "After init:" << endl;
    cout << "m4b channels: " << m4b.channels() << endl;
    cout << "m3b channels: " << m3b.channels() << endl << endl;

    Rect roi(0, 0, 50, 50); // roi

    // Create a new header for the data inside the roi in m3b
    // No data copied, just a new header.
    // So destRoi has same number of channels of m3b
    Mat destRoi = m3b(roi); 


    cout << "After roi:" << endl;
    cout << "m4b channels    : " << m4b.channels() << endl;
    cout << "m3b channels    : " << m3b.channels() << endl;
    cout << "destRoi channels: " << destRoi.channels() << endl << endl;

    // destination type != source type
    // destRoi is newly created with the destination type
    // destRoi doesn't point anymore to the data in m3b and has 4 channels now
    m4b.copyTo(destRoi);

    cout << "After copyTo:" << endl;
    cout << "m4b channels    : " << m4b.channels() << endl;
    cout << "m3b channels    : " << m3b.channels() << endl;
    cout << "destRoi channels: " << destRoi.channels() << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
After init:
m4b channels: 4
m3b channels: 3

After roi:
m4b channels    : 4
m3b channels    : 3
destRoi channels: 3

After copyTo:
m4b channels    : 4
m3b channels    : 3
destRoi channels: 4
```

---

**Solution**

Use both matrices with same number of channels, either by:

1. Load both images as 3 channels matrices `CV_8UC3`. *In fact the images you posted are both 3 channels*
2. use `cvtColor` to convert to the same number of channels, before performing roi and copy operations.

Comment: Very helpful investigation!

Comment: @Miki I changed all the input images to Mat img = imread("path",CV_8UC3). Then also the eroor is there. Error is from Mat.hpp..... inline Mat Mat::operator()(const Range* ranges) const
{
    return Mat(*this, ranges);
}

Comment: @Miki Please have a look https://shrib.com/4BMXuPSVCsrKRLF?v=nc. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: a few notes: 1) edit the code into the question, 2) a struct called `Point` is likely to collide with `cv::Point`, so change the name. Also, why don't you use a `std::vector<cv::Point>` in the first place? 3) `CV_8UC3` is not a valid parameter for `imread`. You should use `IMREAD_COLOR` or `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR` (is the same) 4) apply those changes and let me know

Comment: @Miki I done those changes. Changed my structure name. (It is only for testing. Later the point data will be available from kinect). Now also unhandled exception... It is from inline Mat Mat::operator()( const Rect& roi ) const { return Mat(*this, roi); }..  I have edited in shrib.com/4BMXuPSVCsrKRLF?v=nc also

Comment: @Miki  I have edited in shrib.com/4BMXuPSVCsrKRLF?v=nc

Comment: @Neeraj you should add the code to the question, or better on another question since this seems answered either by me or ypnos

Comment: You should learn how to use a debugger. `roi` exceeds `body` dimension. Set a correct rectangle.

Comment: @Miki Oh sorry. I am new to Windows and visual studio. Only worked with gcc and gdb. ... Sorry

Comment: F5 to start debug and break at first breakpoint, F10 to advance a line, F11 to step into, shift+F11 to step out, F9 to set a breakpoint on the current line, or click new line numbers, etc..

Comment: @Miki Thank you... :)

Answer (score 3):

Your matrix types do not match. One has four channels, the other one three.
Obviously, copying the content of a 4-channel matrix into a 3-channel matrix can not work.

Unfortunately in some circumstances OpenCV silently falls back to creating a new matrix when it cannot work on the old memory. Most probably, this is such a case. As soon as you perform the copy, `destinationROI` starts pointing to new memory.

Note that you might be able to prevent this behavior by declaring `destinationROI` as `Mat3b`. To make your code work however, both source and destination need to carry the same number of channels.

Both assumptions I make here are only educated guesses though, I did not test the code in question.

Comment: I tried to change the format to Mat3b before. But when I do this I am getting errors. I don't know why...

Comment: Did you read my amendmend, "To make your code work however, both source and destination need to carry the same number of channels."?

Comment: Yeah I tried to change all images to Mat3b, then to Mat4b then to Mat.. But everytime I am getting errors... :(

Comment: Maybe you should show us the code and error messages so we can help with that?

Answer (score -1):

your code is too initial. also your images not suit to a perfect result.guess you performed true code on the images you will get an image of who weared to shirt.

```
Mat4b src= imread("path");// to load 4 channel image : imread("path",IMREAD_UNCHANGED); 
Mat3b dest = imread("path");
Rect roi = Rect(179,539,src.cols,src.rows); //src.cols = 1186 and src.rows= 1134 after scaling.
Mat destinationROI = dest(roi);
src.copyTo(destinationROI);
imwrite("destinationROI.png", destinationROI);
```

i can write a code to get following image ( it is photoshopped just to show result) but it is meaningless with your images.

[image]

EDIT 1 :

i edited your code a bit here. take a look //edit 1,2,3 inside the code.

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

float sx, sy;
int tx, ty;

struct TaggingPoint{
int rshx, rshy;
int lshx, lshy;
int topx, topy;
int botx, boty;
}body_points, garment_points;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

Mat shirt;
Mat body;

shirt = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR);
if (shirt.empty())
return -1;

body = imread(argv[2], IMREAD_COLOR);
if (body.empty())
return -1;

body_points.rshx = 418;
body_points.rshy = 706;
body_points.lshx = 1234;
body_points.lshy = 706;
body_points.topx = 838;
body_points.topy = 510;
body_points.botx = 838;
body_points.boty = 1534;

garment_points.rshx = 239;
garment_points.rshy = 147;
garment_points.lshx = 755;
garment_points.lshy = 147;
garment_points.topx = 505;
garment_points.topy = 50;
garment_points.botx = 505;
garment_points.boty = 953;


// edit 1 : when you calculate by this values your shirt image's width will be greater that body image's width
// so to reduce it
sx = (float)(body_points.lshx - body_points.rshx) / (garment_points.lshx - garment_points.rshx)*0.995;
sy = (float)(body_points.boty - body_points.topy) / (garment_points.boty - garment_points.topy);

//scale the image
resize(shirt, shirt, Size(), sx, sy, INTER_LINEAR);

imwrite("shirt.png", shirt);

//translation happened
//  tx = body_points.rshx - (sx * garment_points.rshx);
tx = body_points.rshx - (garment_points.rshx);
ty = body_points.rshy - (sy * garment_points.rshy);

//draw one image over another image
//src.copyTo(dst.rowRange(1, 6).colRange(3, 10));
//  shirt.copyTo(body.rowRange(tx, shirt.rows).colRange(ty, shirt.cols));
//  shirt.copyTo(body.rowRange(100, 1000).colRange(100, 500));

//  cvtColor(shirt, shirt, CV_BGRA2BGR);
//  cvtColor(body, body, CV_BGRA2BGR);


namedWindow("body");
//Rect roi(cv::Point(tx, ty), Size(shirt.size()));

// Edit 2 : Rect.x = 0

Rect roi = Rect(0,ty,shirt.cols,shirt.rows);
Mat destinationROI = body(roi);
//  cvtColor(destinationROI, destinationROI, CV_BGRA2BGR);

// Edit 3 : Create a mask ( it is show purpose only, need improvement )
Mat mask;
cvtColor( shirt, mask, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
mask = mask < 250;

shirt.copyTo(destinationROI,mask);

imwrite("destinationROI.png", destinationROI);

imshow("body", body);
imwrite("body.png", body);

waitKey();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that an answer like "Use Photoshop" is useful here. Also explain why your code works, and what's wrong with OP's one.

Comment: There is no real difference in the code. He just swapped a line but did not address the issue.

Comment: " it is photoshopped just to show result" guess i wrote the code and you get this image. i mean it is useless.

Comment: if you need further assistance please ask a question on OpenCV offical [Q/A](http://answers.opencv.org) forum.